# window.load() does not run on iOS5

Tags: jquery, ios5

I have a very simple jQuery function that hides most elements until the page has finished loading. This function runs on mac and iOS4 but does not seem to be recognized by iOS5. Any suggestions?

```
    $(window).load(function () {
    $('.loading').fadeIn(500).removeClass('loading');
    $('#giffy').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is jQuery being called before your script runs?

-Or-

Have you tried using a different convention like:

```
$(function(){
    //Your stuff here
});
```

Comment: It is good to note that this is the shorthand for:
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready is the preferred method. If you need the event to fire after external resources (images) have loaded, then the best I can offer is to set up an interval, check the height of the image (is not 0) and when every dependent resource passes this test, fire off your event.